# Pandas version control using anaconda desktop launcher

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, anaconda, conda

In an IPython notebook (launched with anaconda desktop), when I print `pd.__name__, pd.__version__` the result is:

pandas 0.14.1

I only have one environment, the root environment, and when I:

```
!conda list -n root
```

I am told that pandas is 0.16.1.

Why is it that these are different? How can I update my pandas version in the notebook?

I have tried pip install and conda update and both tell me that I am using the latest version of pandas.

**More details:**

When I run import `IPython; IPython.__path__` the result is:

/Users/charlie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython

When I execute `conda list -n root` I get:

packages in environment at /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:

conda                     3.12.0                   py27_0
conda-env                 2.1.4                    py27_0
pandas                    0.16.1               np19py27_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py27_0
python                    2.7.8                         0
python-dateutil           2.4.2                    py27_0
pytz                      2015.4                   py27_0
pyyaml                    3.11                     py27_0
requests                  2.7.0                    py27_0
six                       1.9.0                    py27_0
yaml                      0.1.4                         1

Comment: Your last line is strange (``conda list`` should say the packages are located in `/Users/charlie/anaconda`). But why this is, I don't know. Maybe try to reinstall full of anaconda

Comment: It does then list the packages.  But I think what is interesting is that the location is different from the earlier location listed... and I think that is the reason that I am stuck on old package versions

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant that is strange. So for some reason, `conda` is pointing to the wrong python.

Comment: What is your `conda info -a`? You probably need to unset `PYTHONPATH` or remove `~/.local/lib/python2.7`.

Comment: platform : osx-64
conda version : 3.12.0
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 2.7.8.final.0
requests version : 2.7.0
root environment : /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7  (writable)
default environment : /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
envs directories : /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/envs
package cache : /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/pkgs
 channel URLs : https....
 config file : None
 is foreign system : True

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing your pandas again using `conda install`. See [documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/examples/install.html) for re-installing. May be that your update was not successful.

Comment: I just tried and it hasn't work.  It successfully installs using conda install, but in the notebook it still says that I am on v 0.14.1